# Java: Program crashes after inputting two bad values

Tags: java, try-catch, greatest-common-divisor, lcm

I coded a program, that calculates the gcd (greatest common divisor) and lcm (least common multiple). Everything works fine except the `try {...} catch(...) {...}`. Here is the part of the code that doesn't work as I want it to:

```java
try {
    num1 = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
}
catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Your input is not an integer (number w/o decimals)! Try again.");
    System.out.print("Enter your first number: ");
    num1 = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
}
```

When I input e.g. letters, it says:

```
Your input is not an integer (number w/o decimals)! Try again.
Enter your first number:
```

But when I type letters the second time, the program crashes:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "asdf"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:658)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:776)
    at GCDLCMgetter.main(GCDLCMgetter.java:56)
```

It is probably a very simple mistake I made but I can't figure it out...

Thank you

Comment: `num1 = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());` should not be placed within `catch`; I imagine you want to execute this in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your second prompt is inside the catch block. Instead of prompting again inside the catch block, you want to wrap the entire code section in a loop so it comes back around to the try block for the prompt again.
Something like:

```
boolean repeat = true;
while(repeat){
    try{
        //Prompt for input
        repeat = false;
    }catch(Exception e) {
        //Display error message
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your second parseInt method call is not in try catch block. You need to use a loop for this kind of logic.

Answer (score 1):

When the first time you  give letters it goes into `catch` block. Displays the error message. And then executes the line `num1 = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());`
Again you have entered the letters, but this time there is no `try-catch` block to handle this. So it throws error.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, it gets executed twice:

1. Reads a Line at `try{...}`
2. There is an `Exception`
3. The Exception is handled by the `catch(Exception e){...}`
4. The `num1 = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());` inside the `catch(Exception e){...}` cannot be handled. It's not placed inside `try{}`.
5. Execution finished because the last exception cannot be handled by any `catch`.

It seems you're using [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), I would recommend you using a loop whis way:

```
while (sc.hasNextLine()){
    try {
        System.out.print("Enter your first number: ");
        num1 = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Your input is not an integer (number w/o decimals)! Try again.");
    }
}
```

If you're managing integers, it would be interesting using [Scanner.nextInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--)

```
while (sc.hasNextInt()){
    try {
        System.out.print("Enter your first number: ");
        num1 = sc.nextInt());
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Your input is not an integer (number w/o decimals)! Try again.");
    }
}
```